# Conversions of np.timedelta64 to days, weeks, months, etc

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

When I compute the difference between two pandas `datetime64` dates I get `np.timedelta64`. Is there any easy way to convert these deltas into representations like hours, days, weeks, etc.?

I could not find any methods in `np.timedelta64` that facilitate conversions between different units, but it looks like Pandas seems to know how to convert these units to days when printing timedeltas (e.g. I get: `29 days, 23:20:00` in the string representation dataframes). Any way to access this functionality ?

### Update:

Strangely, none of the following work:

```
> df['column_with_times'].days
> df['column_with_times'].apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

but this one does:

```
df['column_with_times'][0].days
```

Comment: As a side note: a `timedelta64` doesn't have hours, days, or weeks if its units are months, years, or generic, only if they're weeks or smaller. I assume you've already got `timedelta64` values in some relevant unit (usually days, seconds, or milliseconds, or nanoseconds), so this isn't an issue for you, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Read the extensive documentation here on how to do exactly that: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-deltas

Comment: @Jeff: I thought he was asking how to do this directly with numpy, not with pandas… but now that I reread it, I think you may be right…

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I missed that @Jeff. You are totally right.

Comment: it IS a big set of documentation :)

Comment: @Jeff I tried several methods without luck (see my Update). This is with `0.15.1`. I wonder if I should open a ticket.

Answer (score 3):

pandas stores timedelta data in the numpy `timedelta64[ns]` type, but also provides the `Timedelta` type to wrap this for more convenience (eg to provide such accessors of the days, hours, .. and other components).

```
In [41]: timedelta_col = pd.Series(pd.timedelta_range('1 days', periods=5, freq='2 h'))

In [42]: timedelta_col
Out[42]:
0   1 days 00:00:00
1   1 days 02:00:00
2   1 days 04:00:00
3   1 days 06:00:00
4   1 days 08:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

To access the different components of a full column (series), you have to use the `.dt` accessor. For example:

```
In [43]: timedelta_col.dt.hours
Out[43]:
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    6
4    8
dtype: int64
```

With `timedelta_col.dt.components` you get a frame with all the different components (days to nanoseconds) as different columns.
When accessing one value of the column above, this gives back a `Timedelta`, and on this you don't need to use the `dt` accessor, but you can access directly the components:

```
In [45]: timedelta_col[0]
Out[45]: Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00')

In [46]: timedelta_col[0].days
Out[46]: 1L
```

So the `.dt` accessor provides access to the attributes of the `Timedelta` scalar, but on the full column. That is the reason you see that `df['column_with_times'][0].days` works but `df['column_with_times'].days` not.
The reason that `df['column_with_times'].apply(lambda x: x.days)` does not work is that apply is given the `timedelta64` values (and not the `Timedelta` pandas type), and these don't have such attributes.